# Android : how to pass a integer value to service using KSOAP in android

Tags: android

Not able to pass an integer value to the service request.The value that reaches service request becomes null
Here is my code

```
private static final String METHOD_NAME ="GetPrivileges";  
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://AuthorizationManagement.ServiceContracts/2007/01/";  
private static final String URL ="http://192.168.5.219/NTLS_Authorization
```

> /AuthorisationManager.asmx";

```
final String SOAP_ACTION ="http://AuthorizationManagement.ServiceContracts/2007/01/GetPrivileges";    
    public void call() {
        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
            pi.type=PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            pi.setName("RoleID");
            pi.setValue(3);
            pi.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
            request.addProperty(pi);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            Object result = envelope.getResponse();

            String resultData = result.toString();
```

Comment: Yes Jinda is right.please post the error you are getting at that point.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void call(int number) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                  String METHOD_NAME ="GetPrivileges";
                   String NAMESPACE = "http://AuthorizationManagement.ServiceContracts/2007/01/";
                   String URL ="http://192.168.5.219/NTLS_Authorization/AuthorisationManager.asmx";
                final String SOAP_ACTION ="http://AuthorizationManagement.ServiceContracts/2007/01/GetPrivileges";
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                request.addProperty("RoleID",number);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


                AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                Object result = envelope.getResponse();

                String resultData = result.toString();
                Log.v("Result==>",resultData);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();        
                }
        }
```

Comment: Even this code doesn't work. Do we need to add any permission in Android manifest file other than  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`

Comment: nope.only you can find the answer by coordinating with the server side.

Comment: i think you have to pass an object to the method not an value.let me try and give u answer in that way.

Answer (score 0):

simply you can add this

```
requestObject.addProperty("RoleID",3);
```

May be try this code  //**note don't put directly number(3 in ur case) instead pass it as parameter ...**

```
    final SoapObject requestObject = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME );          
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = false;
            requestObject.addProperty("RoleID",number);

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(requestObject);
            AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport =new AndroidHttpTransport(Constants.URL);
            try
            {
                androidHttpTransport.call(Constants.SOAP_ACTION+METHOD_NAME, envelope);
                SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                Log.v("result",response.toString());
}
 catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: so the error is  not passing the value.wat is the error showing?can u post it?

Comment: The Response says Role ID cannot be NULL or Negative which is a message given in the service

Comment: it's Role ID or RoleID? check that? if you correctly give a name let me give you a code .

Comment: This is what i get from service wsdl. So i have given the name as RoleID

`<s:complexType name="PrivilegesRequestType">
<s:sequence><s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RoleID" type="s:int"/>
</s:sequence></s:complexType>`

Comment: I have edited the answer...Let me know if you have any success.

Comment: I have declared an int and then passed it to request. But even this does not work
`int number =3;
request.addProperty("RoleID", number);`

Comment: Yes it is a working service which we have consumed in our .net application

Comment: could you give me some moment to test ur code in my application?

Comment: am you unable to connect the url http://192.168.5.219/NTLS_Authorization/AuthorisationManager.asmx ..check in ur browser.

Comment: due to some firewall pretection i cannot access ur system.below i added another answer.

Comment: It is our internal IP. check - http://sarastest.infinitaslearning.net/NTLS_Authorization/AuthorisationManager.asmx

Comment: i also got the same result.check with the webservice here it did not throw any error.might be problem in the service side bacause only handled status message.Ask them in which scenario it will throw this message? all the best.

Comment: When the request object is null i.e PrivilegesRequestType object in my case then we get the message "RoleID_CanNot_Be_Null_Or_Negative" from the service